# &T Into bool where T: Into<bool>

Tags: rust, traits

I have a function with a generic `T` which is `Into<bool>`. I can't figure out how to convert a reference, `&T` into `bool`. My understanding of `Into` or generics are wrong because I thought this would work:

```rust
// error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: From<&T>` is not satisfied
fn ref_bool<T: Into<bool>>(input: &T) -> bool {
    input.into()
//        ^^^^ the trait `From<&T>` is not implemented for `bool`
}
```

How can I fix this so that I can convert `&T` into a `bool`?

Comment: Does `T` implement `Copy`? Note that `Into` consumes `self`, and you can't move an object out of a reference.

Comment: I'm not too great with Rust but I think you should deref and have `T` also have a trait bound of `Copy`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=544ed5056fddad62970c8b4cb5695d91)

Comment: If you want to convert `&T` to `bool` then you need the bound `&T: Into<bool>`. If you want to convert the `T` and not the reference, at a minimum you need `T: Clone` and then you can do `input.clone().into()`. (Bounding on `Clone` is less restrictive than bounding on `Copy`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this method compile by putting the trait bound on `&T`.

```rs
fn ref_bool<'a, T>(input: &'a T) -> bool where &'a T: Into<bool> {
    input.into()
}
```

The explicit lifetime is only necessary because lifetimes in where clauses aren't inferred.

However, this function makes little sense. Any value you pass into it can also be passed into this simpler function:

```rs
fn into_bool<T: Into<bool>>(input: T) -> bool {
    input.into()
}
```

And in that case, it's the same as `Into::into`, so you might as well use `Into::into` directly.

These other solutions might not do what you intend. The `Into` trait is meant for conversions that consume the input, so it's not often implemented for references. Usually non-consuming operations that return a `bool` are specific to the type, like `Vec::is_empty` or `Option::is_none`. There isn't a trait in the standard library for truthiness like you may find in other languages, particularly dynamically typed languages. In rust, you'd typically convert something to a `bool` as soon as possible, before passing it into a function, which avoids the need for a truthiness trait.

Comment: Thanks, the explicit lifetime was what was throwing me off. The function was meant as more of an illustration of what I was trying to do in a larger segment of code.